# How do I add a function to the prototype chain on a primitive type in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

Case in point: Adding a new `split` function to the `string` type. Can't find anything in the docs. I'm using vanilla JS and would like to declare a new type `string` which *adds* my new `split` function. Something like `type mystring = string + function ...`. Maybe an intersection type would work?

Comment: String already has a `split` function, doesn't this mean you're in fact breaking the existing type definitions? There's no feature to do what you want in Flow because adding functions to global prototypes is considered bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, the new function has another name: `splitCSV`.

Comment: Why are you adding it to the prototype to begin with though? Importing the function and then calling `splitCSV(str)` is super easy and much easier for Flow and more maintainable.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Uh, good point. Not sure why it's done like this (legacy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string & {mySplit: Function}` works fine.